# Is it possible LibTooling doesn't change headers?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, libtooling

I have an LibTooling (TimeFlag), which is used to add an flag for every forstmt/whilestmt. And I use `./TimeFlag lalala.cpp --` to insert flags in lalala.cpp

Unfortunately, this tool also will change the headers, even system library.

So is there some ways letting LibTooling  just handle the input file?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possibilities: if using a RecursiveASTVisitor, one could use the SourceManager to determine if the location of the statement or declaration is in the main expansion file:

```
clang::SourceManager &sm(astContext->getSourceManager());
bool const inMainFile(
  sm.isInMainFile( sm.getExpansionLoc( stmt->getLocStart())));
if(inMainFile){
  /* process decl or stmt */
}
else{
  std::cout << "'" << stmt->getNameAsString() << "' is not in main file\n";
}
```

There are several similar methods in SourceManager, such as `isInSystemHeader` to assist with this task.

If you are using AST matchers, you can use `isExpansionInMainFile` to narrow which nodes it matches:

```
auto matcher = forStmt( isExpansionInMainFile());
```

There is a similar matcher, `isExpansionInSystemHeader`.

Comment: Thank u very mach for this. In fact I 'm using the file path to identify  system headers which seems so foolish. I will use isInSystemHeader to improve my code. Thank U again.